# Adding request library to Power BI custom visual

Tags: typescript

I am using Visual Code on a Mac and trying to create a custom Power BI visual including

```
npm install request --save
```

I am adding the request.js file under `tsconfig.json` and `pbiviz.json` using the path

```
"node_modules/request/request.js"
```

I am trying to import request using

```
import * as request from 'request';
```

This gives me the error:

> Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.

Once I change the settings in `tsconfig.json` to `module: "system"`, error messages appear like

> Cannot find name 'IVisual'

I tried many other things, but somehow I cannot make "request" work here.

Answer (score 1):

powerbi-visuals-tools@2.x.x doesn't support external modules and imports statement.

You need to use powerbi-visuals-tools@3.x.x

There is tutorial how to develop Power BI Custom Visual:

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/step-by-step-lab/developing-a-power-bi-custom-visual/

There is short docs how to use the new tools:

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/how-to-guide/migrating-to-powerbi-visuals-tools-3-0/